# How to run nodeJs sever on port 8081 with https

Tags: node.js, ssl

I need to run my node server API on https, not on HTTP. I also have an SSL certificate that runs my site on https but I need to run my node server also on https.

What should I do? Please explain to me the whole thing and steps to make it done.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener

Comment: now my server is running on https but still showing not secure..

Comment: I did from this link https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/#:~:text=To%20start%20your%20https%20server,the%20file)%20on%20the%20terminal.&text=or%20in%20your%20browser%2C%20by,to%20https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%20.

Comment: Is your certificate self-signed or signed by an actual CA?

Comment: I really don't know about this.
I used certbot commands and my site is running on https with full security without any issue but my node server that running on port 8081 is not secured.

Comment: Typically I would just have the app serve http still and then use a reverse proxy which is running https and just proxying to my service. Most hosting providers will support this by just uploading your cert and clicking a few buttons. Can you provide more context about your app and how you plan to host it?